# Localhost not updating files?

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp, localhost

In XAMPP, I changed the folder name containing my html and php files. After I changed it localhost only found the old html. I deleted my cache, saved the text and created a new folder within my htdocs but when I go to the folder called chapter1 which is the new one with localhost/chapter1, and then click on my html folder, it still gives me the old html site. Why isn't it updating? What did the folder name-change do? How can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: Try restartng php-fpm if you are using it

Comment: I don't believe I am using it, how do I check?